# Foreach returns only 1 set of an array

Tags: php

i'm trying to create a method for an http request using this code, but it only picks up 1 set of key and value pair ("key_1"=>"value_1"). how do i get all the array keys and their values?

```
<?php
    $userPostData = [
        'key_1' => "value_1",
        'key_2' => "value_2"
    ];

  foreach($userPostData as $key => $value) {
    $response = $client->post($apiUrl, [
        'json' => [
             $key => urlencode($value),
        ],
        'verify' => false
        ]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_map to urlencode the array values. Also, I think you forgot to encode the array to json, so I did it for you:

```
$userPostData = [
    'key_1' => "value_1",
    'key_2' => "value_2"
];

$userPostData = array_map('urlencode', $userPostData);

$response = $client->post($apiUrl, [
    'json'   => json_encode($userPostData), 
    'verify' => false
]);
```

Comment: seems much better and accurate than mine.+1

Comment: yes i'm not getting exactly what i want but this is taking me somewhere, thanx.